Not able to move elements to the right on a html page
I'm having an issue with element positioning on my web page
I'm trying to code the header from the design. Here is the design:

As you can see, the distance from the border should be the same for the Login, Signup and the logo, and i wasn't able to do that.
here's my code below
html
<header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <svg width="199" height="20" viewBox="0 0 199 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M12.7344 1.11719C12.75 1.42969 12.7578 1.98047 12.7578 2.76953C12.7578 3.55078 12.6328 4.61328 12.3828 5.95703H11.0938C11.0469 3.98047 10.2656 2.78906 8.75 2.38281C8.27344 2.25 7.71094 2.18359 7.0625 2.18359C6.41406 2.18359 5.86328 2.26953 5.41016 2.44141C4.96484 2.61328 4.61719 2.83594 4.36719 3.10938C3.92188 3.58594 3.71875 4.21094 3.75781 4.98438C3.82031 6.17188 4.67969 7.19531 6.33594 8.05469C6.82812 8.3125 7.32031 8.55078 7.8125 8.76953C8.3125 8.98828 8.77734 9.20703 9.20703 9.42578C9.64453 9.63672 10.0664 9.87109 10.4727 10.1289C10.8789 10.3789 11.2578 10.6484 11.6094 10.9375C11.9688 11.2266 12.2852 11.543 12.5586 11.8867C13.1367 12.6211 13.457 13.4141 13.5195 14.2656C13.5195 15.8516 12.8906 17.0859 11.6328 17.9688C10.4688 18.7812 8.93359 19.1875 7.02734 19.1875C6.41797 19.1875 5.56641 19.0859 4.47266 18.8828C3.37891 18.6797 2.61719 18.5781 2.1875 18.5781C1.76562 18.5781 1.39844 18.6016 1.08594 18.6484L0.992188 18.625C0.984375 18.4531 0.980469 18.2812 0.980469 18.1094V17.6172C0.980469 15.9688 1.07031 14.6328 1.25 13.6094H2.57422C2.66797 15.8047 3.46094 17.1484 4.95312 17.6406C5.48438 17.8203 6.08203 17.9102 6.74609 17.9102C7.41797 17.9102 7.99609 17.8359 8.48047 17.6875C8.96484 17.5312 9.37891 17.3203 9.72266 17.0547C10.4414 16.5 10.8008 15.7891 10.8008 14.9219C10.7227 13.6875 9.78125 12.6406 7.97656 11.7812C7.45312 11.5312 7.03125 11.3359 6.71094 11.1953L6.11328 10.9375C6.02734 10.8984 5.81641 10.8086 5.48047 10.668C5.15234 10.5273 4.71094 10.2852 4.15625 9.94141C3.60938 9.59766 3.12109 9.20312 2.69141 8.75781C1.75391 7.78125 1.26953 6.66797 1.23828 5.41797C1.20703 4.06641 1.76562 2.96875 2.91406 2.125C4.03906 1.30469 5.51562 0.894531 7.34375 0.894531C7.625 0.894531 8.05469 0.929688 8.63281 1L10.1094 1.1875C10.5312 1.24219 10.9531 1.26953 11.375 1.26953C11.8047 1.26953 12.2578 1.21875 12.7344 1.11719ZM34.2008 2.45312C34.0914 2.42187 34.0133 2.40625 33.9664 2.40625C33.9273 2.40625 33.8141 2.41016 33.6266 2.41797C33.4391 2.42578 33.2555 2.46094 33.0758 2.52344C32.9039 2.57813 32.6969 2.6875 32.4547 2.85156C31.9 3.25 31.2633 3.86328 30.5445 4.69141L26.3258 9.55469C27.4742 10.3672 28.8219 11.7188 30.3687 13.6094C30.7828 14.125 31.1344 14.5938 31.4234 15.0156C31.7203 15.4297 31.9977 15.8047 32.2555 16.1406C32.5133 16.4688 32.7594 16.75 32.9937 16.9844C33.4625 17.4531 33.8609 17.6875 34.1891 17.6875C34.525 17.6875 34.8219 17.6523 35.0797 17.582L35.0328 19H32.2789C31.4195 19 30.6344 18.5508 29.9234 17.6523C29.6812 17.3477 29.4547 17.0156 29.2437 16.6562C28.6109 15.625 28.1461 14.8906 27.8492 14.4531L26.9703 13.1875C25.9703 11.8125 25.1422 10.8711 24.4859 10.3633H23.3961V15.4844C23.3961 16.2656 23.4469 16.7812 23.5484 17.0312C23.7437 17.4844 24.0875 17.7109 24.5797 17.7109C24.9 17.7109 25.2984 17.6562 25.775 17.5469L25.6227 19H18.9195L19.0602 17.7109C19.818 17.7109 20.3062 17.5547 20.525 17.2422C20.7437 16.9297 20.8531 16.2227 20.8531 15.1211V4.67969C20.8531 3.83594 20.8023 3.29297 20.7008 3.05078C20.607 2.80078 20.4977 2.63672 20.3727 2.55859C20.2477 2.47266 20.1187 2.42969 19.9859 2.42969C19.8609 2.42969 19.7516 2.43359 19.6578 2.44141C19.5641 2.44141 19.4625 2.44531 19.3531 2.45312L19.0484 2.47656C18.9469 2.48438 18.857 2.49219 18.7789 2.5L18.9898 1.07031H25.3297L25.1539 2.42969C24.482 2.42969 24.0484 2.53125 23.8531 2.73438C23.5484 3.07031 23.3961 3.67969 23.3961 4.5625V9.01562H24.2047C24.4703 9.01562 24.6852 8.94922 24.8492 8.81641L28.1656 5.00781C28.4859 4.63281 28.6812 4.38672 28.7516 4.26953C28.9 4.02734 29.0289 3.83594 29.1383 3.69531C29.443 3.33594 29.5953 3.08203 29.5953 2.93359C29.5953 2.54297 29.3844 2.34766 28.9625 2.34766C28.5797 2.34766 28.2242 2.38281 27.8961 2.45312L28.0953 1.07031H34.4117L34.2008 2.45312ZM44.218 17.2305C44.3352 17.418 44.4797 17.5469 44.6516 17.6172C44.8312 17.6797 45.0266 17.7109 45.2375 17.7109C45.4562 17.7109 45.8586 17.6523 46.4445 17.5352L46.3039 19H39.1203L39.2492 17.7109C40.0148 17.7109 40.5695 17.5312 40.9133 17.1719C41.3117 16.7422 41.5109 16.0195 41.5109 15.0039L41.4992 4.77344C41.4992 3.44531 41.3 2.69141 40.9016 2.51172C40.7766 2.45703 40.632 2.42969 40.468 2.42969C40.007 2.42969 39.5891 2.46484 39.2141 2.53516L39.4016 1.07031H46.257L46.0695 2.42969C45.1867 2.42969 44.6242 2.57813 44.382 2.875C44.1555 3.14063 44.0422 3.74609 44.0422 4.69141V15.8242C44.0422 16.5742 44.1008 17.043 44.218 17.2305ZM65.1102 13.7617C65.1492 14.1914 65.1688 14.6367 65.1688 15.0977C65.1688 15.7461 65.0984 16.4531 64.9578 17.2188C64.7703 18.2031 64.6688 18.7969 64.6531 19H50.9188L51.0594 17.6523C51.8094 17.668 52.3328 17.5156 52.6297 17.1953C52.9813 16.8281 53.157 16.1367 53.157 15.1211L53.1453 4.375C53.1453 3.53125 53.0906 3.01562 52.9813 2.82812C52.8719 2.64062 52.7547 2.52734 52.6297 2.48828C52.5125 2.44922 52.3445 2.42969 52.1258 2.42969C51.9148 2.42969 51.7313 2.44531 51.575 2.47656C51.3875 2.52344 51.2625 2.54688 51.2 2.54688L51.3875 1.07031H58.4188L58.2547 2.44141C57.2469 2.44141 56.618 2.51953 56.368 2.67578C56.118 2.83203 55.9461 3.03516 55.8523 3.28516C55.7664 3.53516 55.7234 3.875 55.7234 4.30469L55.7352 4.66797V15.7188C55.7352 16.875 56.118 17.5195 56.8836 17.6523C57.1102 17.6914 57.3523 17.7109 57.6102 17.7109H59.5438C61.6922 17.7109 62.9734 16.8867 63.3875 15.2383C63.5125 14.7617 63.6023 14.2695 63.657 13.7617H65.1102ZM83.5414 13.7617C83.5805 14.1914 83.6 14.6367 83.6 15.0977C83.6 15.7461 83.5297 16.4531 83.3891 17.2188C83.2016 18.2031 83.1 18.7969 83.0844 19H69.35L69.4906 17.6523C70.2406 17.668 70.7641 17.5156 71.0609 17.1953C71.4125 16.8281 71.5883 16.1367 71.5883 15.1211L71.5766 4.375C71.5766 3.53125 71.5219 3.01562 71.4125 2.82812C71.3031 2.64062 71.1859 2.52734 71.0609 2.48828C70.9437 2.44922 70.7758 2.42969 70.557 2.42969C70.3461 2.42969 70.1625 2.44531 70.0062 2.47656C69.8187 2.52344 69.6937 2.54688 69.6312 2.54688L69.8187 1.07031H76.85L76.6859 2.44141C75.6781 2.44141 75.0492 2.51953 74.7992 2.67578C74.5492 2.83203 74.3773 3.03516 74.2836 3.28516C74.1977 3.53516 74.1547 3.875 74.1547 4.30469L74.1664 4.66797V15.7188C74.1664 16.875 74.5492 17.5195 75.3148 17.6523C75.5414 17.6914 75.7836 17.7109 76.0414 17.7109H77.975C80.1234 17.7109 81.4047 16.8867 81.8187 15.2383C81.9437 14.7617 82.0336 14.2695 82.0883 13.7617H83.5414ZM96.2539 19.1875L91.8477 19.0117H88.2617L88.3555 17.7109C89.0664 17.7109 89.5508 17.6172 89.8086 17.4297C90.2695 17.0781 90.5 16.5 90.5 15.6953V4.67969C90.5 3.4375 90.2578 2.71875 89.7734 2.52344C89.6328 2.46094 89.4023 2.42969 89.082 2.42969C88.7617 2.42969 88.4961 2.47266 88.2852 2.55859L88.3906 1.07031H91.8477C92.3789 1.05469 92.8945 1.03516 93.3945 1.01172C94.7383 0.933594 95.8242 0.894531 96.6523 0.894531C97.4883 0.894531 98.2852 0.996094 99.043 1.19922C99.8086 1.39453 100.445 1.67578 100.953 2.04297C101.977 2.78516 102.488 3.8125 102.488 5.125C102.488 6.16406 102.18 7.07031 101.562 7.84375C101.055 8.47656 100.371 8.96484 99.5117 9.30859C100.973 9.44141 102.094 9.92969 102.875 10.7734C103.578 11.5234 103.93 12.457 103.93 13.5742C103.93 15.207 103.273 16.5352 101.961 17.5586C100.562 18.6445 98.6602 19.1875 96.2539 19.1875ZM99.6875 5.35938C99.6875 3.28906 98.3281 2.25391 95.6094 2.25391C94.7109 2.25391 94.0977 2.28906 93.7695 2.35938L93.043 2.5V8.98047H96.4531C98.1406 8.98047 99.1602 8.30078 99.5117 6.94141C99.6289 6.48828 99.6875 5.96094 99.6875 5.35938ZM93.043 10.3398L93.0664 16.2344C93.0664 16.8906 93.3047 17.3242 93.7812 17.5352C94.2344 17.7305 95.0391 17.8281 96.1953 17.8281C97.3516 17.8281 98.2188 17.7305 98.7969 17.5352C99.3828 17.332 99.8438 17.0508 100.18 16.6914C100.781 16.0586 101.082 15.0859 101.082 13.7734C101.082 12.4609 100.734 11.5625 100.039 11.0781C99.3203 10.5781 97.9727 10.3281 95.9961 10.3281L93.043 10.3398ZM113.701 17.1484C113.826 17.3594 113.974 17.5078 114.146 17.5938C114.318 17.6719 114.568 17.7109 114.896 17.7109C115.232 17.7109 115.65 17.6484 116.15 17.5234L116.021 19H109.107L109.248 17.7109C110.052 17.6953 110.564 17.4844 110.783 17.0781C110.97 16.75 111.064 16.0234 111.064 14.8984L111.052 4.33984C111.052 3.57422 111.017 3.10156 110.947 2.92188C110.806 2.59375 110.486 2.42969 109.986 2.42969C109.588 2.42969 109.181 2.47656 108.767 2.57031L108.955 1.07031H112.33L117.088 0.894531C119.963 0.894531 121.783 1.78906 122.548 3.57812C122.783 4.14062 122.9 4.77734 122.9 5.48828C122.9 6.19141 122.771 6.83594 122.513 7.42188C122.255 8.00781 121.923 8.52344 121.517 8.96875C120.705 9.85938 119.759 10.4336 118.681 10.6914C119.463 11.0898 120.306 12.0547 121.213 13.5859L122.56 15.8828C123.255 17.0312 123.798 17.6055 124.189 17.6055C124.494 17.6211 124.826 17.5703 125.185 17.4531L125.127 19H123.345C122.166 19 121.213 18.5977 120.486 17.793C120.127 17.3398 119.81 16.7539 119.537 16.0352L118.892 14.3945C118.603 13.6758 118.259 13.0547 117.861 12.5312C117.463 12 117.127 11.6445 116.853 11.4648C116.353 11.1445 115.572 10.9844 114.509 10.9844H113.525V15.7188C113.525 16.4609 113.584 16.9375 113.701 17.1484ZM117.908 2.5C117.408 2.33594 116.963 2.25391 116.572 2.25391H115.119C114.533 2.25391 114.002 2.31641 113.525 2.44141V9.57812H116.349C117.412 9.5625 118.298 9.23438 119.009 8.59375C119.767 7.89844 120.146 6.98438 120.146 5.85156C120.146 4.08594 119.4 2.96875 117.908 2.5ZM134.288 17.2305C134.405 17.418 134.55 17.5469 134.722 17.6172C134.902 17.6797 135.097 17.7109 135.308 17.7109C135.527 17.7109 135.929 17.6523 136.515 17.5352L136.374 19H129.191L129.32 17.7109C130.085 17.7109 130.64 17.5312 130.984 17.1719C131.382 16.7422 131.581 16.0195 131.581 15.0039L131.57 4.77344C131.57 3.44531 131.37 2.69141 130.972 2.51172C130.847 2.45703 130.702 2.42969 130.538 2.42969C130.077 2.42969 129.659 2.46484 129.284 2.53516L129.472 1.07031H136.327L136.14 2.42969C135.257 2.42969 134.695 2.57813 134.452 2.875C134.226 3.14063 134.113 3.74609 134.113 4.69141V15.8242C134.113 16.5742 134.171 17.043 134.288 17.2305ZM148.548 19.1758L144.634 19.0117L141.341 19L141.423 17.7109C142.126 17.7109 142.595 17.6094 142.829 17.4062C143.243 17.0469 143.45 16.4609 143.45 15.6484V4.59766C143.45 3.77734 143.368 3.24609 143.204 3.00391C143.04 2.75391 142.88 2.59375 142.723 2.52344C142.567 2.45312 142.372 2.41797 142.137 2.41797C141.903 2.41797 141.634 2.46484 141.329 2.55859L141.446 1.07031H144.399L148.677 0.894531C154.739 0.894531 157.77 3.76953 157.77 9.51953C157.77 12.4336 156.93 14.7695 155.251 16.5273C153.563 18.293 151.329 19.1758 148.548 19.1758ZM149.919 2.40625C149.302 2.30469 148.665 2.25391 148.009 2.25391C147.36 2.25391 146.688 2.33203 145.993 2.48828V16.5625C145.993 16.9531 146.02 17.1953 146.075 17.2891C146.137 17.3828 146.227 17.4531 146.345 17.5C146.462 17.5391 146.63 17.5703 146.848 17.5938C147.223 17.6328 147.887 17.6523 148.841 17.6523C149.802 17.6523 150.649 17.5117 151.384 17.2305C152.118 16.9414 152.751 16.4922 153.282 15.8828C154.407 14.5781 154.97 12.6367 154.97 10.0586C154.97 5.51172 153.286 2.96094 149.919 2.40625ZM178.299 17.8633C176.752 18.7461 174.553 19.1875 171.702 19.1875C168.491 19.1875 166.057 18.375 164.401 16.75C162.815 15.1953 162.022 13.0273 162.022 10.2461C162.022 7.70703 162.811 5.5625 164.389 3.8125C165.498 2.59375 166.959 1.74219 168.772 1.25781C169.702 1.01562 170.627 0.894531 171.549 0.894531C172.627 0.894531 173.655 0.953125 174.631 1.07031C176.163 1.26563 177.166 1.36328 177.643 1.36328L178.065 1.35156C178.065 2.84375 177.955 4.41797 177.737 6.07422H176.108C176.014 4.55859 175.67 3.52344 175.077 2.96875C174.491 2.41406 173.51 2.13672 172.135 2.13672C170.76 2.13672 169.616 2.34766 168.702 2.76953C167.795 3.18359 167.057 3.74219 166.487 4.44531C165.401 5.78125 164.858 7.57812 164.858 9.83594C164.858 13.5547 166.178 15.9922 168.819 17.1484C169.772 17.5625 170.83 17.7695 171.995 17.7695C173.87 17.7695 175.073 17.4258 175.604 16.7383V13.1289C175.604 12.0039 175.17 11.3984 174.303 11.3125C174.069 11.2891 173.78 11.2773 173.436 11.2773C173.092 11.2773 172.768 11.3047 172.463 11.3594L172.58 9.77734H179.705L179.541 11.2539C179.174 11.2617 178.885 11.3008 178.674 11.3711C178.463 11.4336 178.303 11.5781 178.194 11.8047C178.03 12.1562 177.948 13.0547 177.948 14.5C177.948 16.1719 178.065 17.293 178.299 17.8633ZM194.34 11.9688L194.316 12.3438H192.875C192.82 11.4609 192.719 10.9062 192.57 10.6797C192.305 10.2812 191.824 10.082 191.129 10.082H188.773V15.7305C188.773 16.4883 188.918 16.9922 189.207 17.2422C189.488 17.4844 190.094 17.6211 191.023 17.6523H193.262C194.824 17.6523 195.902 16.9766 196.496 15.625C196.684 15.2031 196.809 14.7266 196.871 14.1953H198.324C198.324 15.0859 198.234 16.0234 198.055 17.0078L197.703 19H184.168L184.367 17.7109C185.148 17.7109 185.66 17.5391 185.902 17.1953C186.121 16.8984 186.23 16.3008 186.23 15.4023V4.69141C186.23 3.18359 185.891 2.42969 185.211 2.42969C184.93 2.42969 184.633 2.46484 184.32 2.53516L184.461 1.07031H193.555C195.438 1.07031 196.848 1.00781 197.785 0.882812C197.785 2.13281 197.664 3.38281 197.422 4.63281C197.359 4.92969 197.305 5.15625 197.258 5.3125H196.062C195.984 4.04688 195.742 3.24609 195.336 2.91016C195.109 2.72266 194.812 2.60547 194.445 2.55859C194.086 2.51172 193.633 2.48828 193.086 2.48828H188.773V8.75781H191.199C191.98 8.75781 192.492 8.58984 192.734 8.25391C192.891 8.04297 193.016 7.55078 193.109 6.77734L194.539 6.76562L194.551 7.38672C194.551 8.37891 194.48 9.90625 194.34 11.9688Z" fill="black"/>
                </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search for anything" class="search">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="teach-link">Teach On SkillBridge</a>
        <div class="cart-icon">
            <a href="#">
                <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 35 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_230_321)">
                    <path d="M26.0313 22.3999L30.3144 5.62954H35V2.99347H28.2669L27.2572 6.9468L0 6.9273L2.89785 22.3998H26.0313V22.3999ZM26.5842 9.5824L23.9839 19.7638H5.08602L3.176 9.56565L26.5842 9.5824Z" fill="black"/>
                    <path d="M22.4231 32.0066C24.7475 32.0066 26.6386 30.1154 26.6386 27.791C26.6386 25.4666 24.7475 23.5756 22.4231 23.5756H6.54073C4.2163 23.5756 2.3252 25.4666 2.3252 27.791C2.3252 30.1154 4.21626 32.0066 6.54073 32.0066C8.8652 32.0066 10.7562 30.1154 10.7562 27.791C10.7562 27.2328 10.6469 26.6997 10.4489 26.2116H18.5149C18.3169 26.6997 18.2075 27.2328 18.2075 27.791C18.2076 30.1154 20.0986 32.0066 22.4231 32.0066ZM8.12016 27.791C8.12016 28.662 7.41164 29.3705 6.54073 29.3705C5.66982 29.3705 4.96126 28.662 4.96126 27.791C4.96126 26.9201 5.66978 26.2116 6.54073 26.2116C7.41164 26.2116 8.12016 26.9201 8.12016 27.791ZM24.0025 27.791C24.0025 28.662 23.294 29.3705 22.4231 29.3705C21.5522 29.3705 20.8437 28.662 20.8437 27.791C20.8437 26.9201 21.5522 26.2116 22.4231 26.2116C23.294 26.2116 24.0025 26.9201 24.0025 27.791Z" fill="black"/>
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                    <clipPath id="clip0_230_321">
                    <rect width="35" height="35" fill="white"/>
                    </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                    </svg>   
            </a>             
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="login-btn">Log in</a>
        <a href="#" class="signup-btn">Sign up</a>
    </header>

css
* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
}

body {
    overflow-x: 0;
    overflow-y: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 85px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 25px;
}

.search-bar .search {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #B8B8B8;
    border-radius: 40px;
    width: 434px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #B8B8B8;
}

.search[type=text] {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #F9FAFB;
    background-image: url('Icon_awesome-search.svg');
    background-position: 25px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 60px;
}


.teach-link, .login-btn, .signup-btn {
    /* margin: 0 10px; */
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.teach-link {
    font-size: 13px;
    align-items: center;
    /* margin-right: 38px; */
}

.login-btn, .signup-btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /* padding: 8px 16px; */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100px;
}

.login-btn {
    float: right;
}

.signup-btn {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    float: right;
}

.cart-icon {
    /* font-size: 18px; */
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

Float: right didn't make any difference at all. How do i make login-btn, signup-btn and cart-icon start from the right?
Pls help

You are taking margin left 60px which is causing more gap. What i prefer is take header in 1 element then width:80%, margin:0 auto and it will automatically adjust gap in every screen/ratio.

Adding flex: 1 1 auto; to .teach-link will make the previous element take up as much space as possible， and the following elements will be squeezed to the far right.
.teach-link {
    font-size: 13px;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    /* margin-right: 38px; */
}


he is asking for the same gap to the right as to the left(logo) but not to move totally in right.

@Leothelion, I guess he is asking about aligning the buttons to the right.

@Leothelion could you revoke the down vote? seems it has already been accepted...

no i did not and also still saying this is not the answer as question is asking for the same gap but not the align but ok if he accepted it then great.

"should be ok" is not the best way to explain what your code does and how it will fix the issue.

@MrUpsidown thanks for the comment, the answer has been updated.

What you are trying to do is center all the header content.
This snippet does this by using justify-content.
It therefore also removes the 60px margin setting on logo.
You may want to introduce some sort of margin to separate the cart logo from the text that is to its left.


* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
}

body {
  overflow-x: 0;
  overflow-y: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 85px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: pink;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*margin-left: 60px;*/
}

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.search-bar .search {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #B8B8B8;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 434px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #B8B8B8;
}

.search[type=text] {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #F9FAFB;
  background-image: url('Icon_awesome-search.svg');
  background-position: 25px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.teach-link,
.login-btn,
.signup-btn {
  /* margin: 0 10px; */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.teach-link {
  font-size: 13px;
  align-items: center;
  /* margin-right: 38px; */
}

.login-btn,
.signup-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* padding: 8px 16px; */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
}

.login-btn {
  float: right;
}

.signup-btn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}

.cart-icon {
  /* font-size: 18px; */
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <svg width="199" height="20" viewBox="0 0 199 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M12.7344 1.11719C12.75 1.42969 12.7578 1.98047 12.7578 2.76953C12.7578 3.55078 12.6328 4.61328 12.3828 5.95703H11.0938C11.0469 3.98047 10.2656 2.78906 8.75 2.38281C8.27344 2.25 7.71094 2.18359 7.0625 2.18359C6.41406 2.18359 5.86328 2.26953 5.41016 2.44141C4.96484 2.61328 4.61719 2.83594 4.36719 3.10938C3.92188 3.58594 3.71875 4.21094 3.75781 4.98438C3.82031 6.17188 4.67969 7.19531 6.33594 8.05469C6.82812 8.3125 7.32031 8.55078 7.8125 8.76953C8.3125 8.98828 8.77734 9.20703 9.20703 9.42578C9.64453 9.63672 10.0664 9.87109 10.4727 10.1289C10.8789 10.3789 11.2578 10.6484 11.6094 10.9375C11.9688 11.2266 12.2852 11.543 12.5586 11.8867C13.1367 12.6211 13.457 13.4141 13.5195 14.2656C13.5195 15.8516 12.8906 17.0859 11.6328 17.9688C10.4688 18.7812 8.93359 19.1875 7.02734 19.1875C6.41797 19.1875 5.56641 19.0859 4.47266 18.8828C3.37891 18.6797 2.61719 18.5781 2.1875 18.5781C1.76562 18.5781 1.39844 18.6016 1.08594 18.6484L0.992188 18.625C0.984375 18.4531 0.980469 18.2812 0.980469 18.1094V17.6172C0.980469 15.9688 1.07031 14.6328 1.25 13.6094H2.57422C2.66797 15.8047 3.46094 17.1484 4.95312 17.6406C5.48438 17.8203 6.08203 17.9102 6.74609 17.9102C7.41797 17.9102 7.99609 17.8359 8.48047 17.6875C8.96484 17.5312 9.37891 17.3203 9.72266 17.0547C10.4414 16.5 10.8008 15.7891 10.8008 14.9219C10.7227 13.6875 9.78125 12.6406 7.97656 11.7812C7.45312 11.5312 7.03125 11.3359 6.71094 11.1953L6.11328 10.9375C6.02734 10.8984 5.81641 10.8086 5.48047 10.668C5.15234 10.5273 4.71094 10.2852 4.15625 9.94141C3.60938 9.59766 3.12109 9.20312 2.69141 8.75781C1.75391 7.78125 1.26953 6.66797 1.23828 5.41797C1.20703 4.06641 1.76562 2.96875 2.91406 2.125C4.03906 1.30469 5.51562 0.894531 7.34375 0.894531C7.625 0.894531 8.05469 0.929688 8.63281 1L10.1094 1.1875C10.5312 1.24219 10.9531 1.26953 11.375 1.26953C11.8047 1.26953 12.2578 1.21875 12.7344 1.11719ZM34.2008 2.45312C34.0914 2.42187 34.0133 2.40625 33.9664 2.40625C33.9273 2.40625 33.8141 2.41016 33.6266 2.41797C33.4391 2.42578 33.2555 2.46094 33.0758 2.52344C32.9039 2.57813 32.6969 2.6875 32.4547 2.85156C31.9 3.25 31.2633 3.86328 30.5445 4.69141L26.3258 9.55469C27.4742 10.3672 28.8219 11.7188 30.3687 13.6094C30.7828 14.125 31.1344 14.5938 31.4234 15.0156C31.7203 15.4297 31.9977 15.8047 32.2555 16.1406C32.5133 16.4688 32.7594 16.75 32.9937 16.9844C33.4625 17.4531 33.8609 17.6875 34.1891 17.6875C34.525 17.6875 34.8219 17.6523 35.0797 17.582L35.0328 19H32.2789C31.4195 19 30.6344 18.5508 29.9234 17.6523C29.6812 17.3477 29.4547 17.0156 29.2437 16.6562C28.6109 15.625 28.1461 14.8906 27.8492 14.4531L26.9703 13.1875C25.9703 11.8125 25.1422 10.8711 24.4859 10.3633H23.3961V15.4844C23.3961 16.2656 23.4469 16.7812 23.5484 17.0312C23.7437 17.4844 24.0875 17.7109 24.5797 17.7109C24.9 17.7109 25.2984 17.6562 25.775 17.5469L25.6227 19H18.9195L19.0602 17.7109C19.818 17.7109 20.3062 17.5547 20.525 17.2422C20.7437 16.9297 20.8531 16.2227 20.8531 15.1211V4.67969C20.8531 3.83594 20.8023 3.29297 20.7008 3.05078C20.607 2.80078 20.4977 2.63672 20.3727 2.55859C20.2477 2.47266 20.1187 2.42969 19.9859 2.42969C19.8609 2.42969 19.7516 2.43359 19.6578 2.44141C19.5641 2.44141 19.4625 2.44531 19.3531 2.45312L19.0484 2.47656C18.9469 2.48438 18.857 2.49219 18.7789 2.5L18.9898 1.07031H25.3297L25.1539 2.42969C24.482 2.42969 24.0484 2.53125 23.8531 2.73438C23.5484 3.07031 23.3961 3.67969 23.3961 4.5625V9.01562H24.2047C24.4703 9.01562 24.6852 8.94922 24.8492 8.81641L28.1656 5.00781C28.4859 4.63281 28.6812 4.38672 28.7516 4.26953C28.9 4.02734 29.0289 3.83594 29.1383 3.69531C29.443 3.33594 29.5953 3.08203 29.5953 2.93359C29.5953 2.54297 29.3844 2.34766 28.9625 2.34766C28.5797 2.34766 28.2242 2.38281 27.8961 2.45312L28.0953 1.07031H34.4117L34.2008 2.45312ZM44.218 17.2305C44.3352 17.418 44.4797 17.5469 44.6516 17.6172C44.8312 17.6797 45.0266 17.7109 45.2375 17.7109C45.4562 17.7109 45.8586 17.6523 46.4445 17.5352L46.3039 19H39.1203L39.2492 17.7109C40.0148 17.7109 40.5695 17.5312 40.9133 17.1719C41.3117 16.7422 41.5109 16.0195 41.5109 15.0039L41.4992 4.77344C41.4992 3.44531 41.3 2.69141 40.9016 2.51172C40.7766 2.45703 40.632 2.42969 40.468 2.42969C40.007 2.42969 39.5891 2.46484 39.2141 2.53516L39.4016 1.07031H46.257L46.0695 2.42969C45.1867 2.42969 44.6242 2.57813 44.382 2.875C44.1555 3.14063 44.0422 3.74609 44.0422 4.69141V15.8242C44.0422 16.5742 44.1008 17.043 44.218 17.2305ZM65.1102 13.7617C65.1492 14.1914 65.1688 14.6367 65.1688 15.0977C65.1688 15.7461 65.0984 16.4531 64.9578 17.2188C64.7703 18.2031 64.6688 18.7969 64.6531 19H50.9188L51.0594 17.6523C51.8094 17.668 52.3328 17.5156 52.6297 17.1953C52.9813 16.8281 53.157 16.1367 53.157 15.1211L53.1453 4.375C53.1453 3.53125 53.0906 3.01562 52.9813 2.82812C52.8719 2.64062 52.7547 2.52734 52.6297 2.48828C52.5125 2.44922 52.3445 2.42969 52.1258 2.42969C51.9148 2.42969 51.7313 2.44531 51.575 2.47656C51.3875 2.52344 51.2625 2.54688 51.2 2.54688L51.3875 1.07031H58.4188L58.2547 2.44141C57.2469 2.44141 56.618 2.51953 56.368 2.67578C56.118 2.83203 55.9461 3.03516 55.8523 3.28516C55.7664 3.53516 55.7234 3.875 55.7234 4.30469L55.7352 4.66797V15.7188C55.7352 16.875 56.118 17.5195 56.8836 17.6523C57.1102 17.6914 57.3523 17.7109 57.6102 17.7109H59.5438C61.6922 17.7109 62.9734 16.8867 63.3875 15.2383C63.5125 14.7617 63.6023 14.2695 63.657 13.7617H65.1102ZM83.5414 13.7617C83.5805 14.1914 83.6 14.6367 83.6 15.0977C83.6 15.7461 83.5297 16.4531 83.3891 17.2188C83.2016 18.2031 83.1 18.7969 83.0844 19H69.35L69.4906 17.6523C70.2406 17.668 70.7641 17.5156 71.0609 17.1953C71.4125 16.8281 71.5883 16.1367 71.5883 15.1211L71.5766 4.375C71.5766 3.53125 71.5219 3.01562 71.4125 2.82812C71.3031 2.64062 71.1859 2.52734 71.0609 2.48828C70.9437 2.44922 70.7758 2.42969 70.557 2.42969C70.3461 2.42969 70.1625 2.44531 70.0062 2.47656C69.8187 2.52344 69.6937 2.54688 69.6312 2.54688L69.8187 1.07031H76.85L76.6859 2.44141C75.6781 2.44141 75.0492 2.51953 74.7992 2.67578C74.5492 2.83203 74.3773 3.03516 74.2836 3.28516C74.1977 3.53516 74.1547 3.875 74.1547 4.30469L74.1664 4.66797V15.7188C74.1664 16.875 74.5492 17.5195 75.3148 17.6523C75.5414 17.6914 75.7836 17.7109 76.0414 17.7109H77.975C80.1234 17.7109 81.4047 16.8867 81.8187 15.2383C81.9437 14.7617 82.0336 14.2695 82.0883 13.7617H83.5414ZM96.2539 19.1875L91.8477 19.0117H88.2617L88.3555 17.7109C89.0664 17.7109 89.5508 17.6172 89.8086 17.4297C90.2695 17.0781 90.5 16.5 90.5 15.6953V4.67969C90.5 3.4375 90.2578 2.71875 89.7734 2.52344C89.6328 2.46094 89.4023 2.42969 89.082 2.42969C88.7617 2.42969 88.4961 2.47266 88.2852 2.55859L88.3906 1.07031H91.8477C92.3789 1.05469 92.8945 1.03516 93.3945 1.01172C94.7383 0.933594 95.8242 0.894531 96.6523 0.894531C97.4883 0.894531 98.2852 0.996094 99.043 1.19922C99.8086 1.39453 100.445 1.67578 100.953 2.04297C101.977 2.78516 102.488 3.8125 102.488 5.125C102.488 6.16406 102.18 7.07031 101.562 7.84375C101.055 8.47656 100.371 8.96484 99.5117 9.30859C100.973 9.44141 102.094 9.92969 102.875 10.7734C103.578 11.5234 103.93 12.457 103.93 13.5742C103.93 15.207 103.273 16.5352 101.961 17.5586C100.562 18.6445 98.6602 19.1875 96.2539 19.1875ZM99.6875 5.35938C99.6875 3.28906 98.3281 2.25391 95.6094 2.25391C94.7109 2.25391 94.0977 2.28906 93.7695 2.35938L93.043 2.5V8.98047H96.4531C98.1406 8.98047 99.1602 8.30078 99.5117 6.94141C99.6289 6.48828 99.6875 5.96094 99.6875 5.35938ZM93.043 10.3398L93.0664 16.2344C93.0664 16.8906 93.3047 17.3242 93.7812 17.5352C94.2344 17.7305 95.0391 17.8281 96.1953 17.8281C97.3516 17.8281 98.2188 17.7305 98.7969 17.5352C99.3828 17.332 99.8438 17.0508 100.18 16.6914C100.781 16.0586 101.082 15.0859 101.082 13.7734C101.082 12.4609 100.734 11.5625 100.039 11.0781C99.3203 10.5781 97.9727 10.3281 95.9961 10.3281L93.043 10.3398ZM113.701 17.1484C113.826 17.3594 113.974 17.5078 114.146 17.5938C114.318 17.6719 114.568 17.7109 114.896 17.7109C115.232 17.7109 115.65 17.6484 116.15 17.5234L116.021 19H109.107L109.248 17.7109C110.052 17.6953 110.564 17.4844 110.783 17.0781C110.97 16.75 111.064 16.0234 111.064 14.8984L111.052 4.33984C111.052 3.57422 111.017 3.10156 110.947 2.92188C110.806 2.59375 110.486 2.42969 109.986 2.42969C109.588 2.42969 109.181 2.47656 108.767 2.57031L108.955 1.07031H112.33L117.088 0.894531C119.963 0.894531 121.783 1.78906 122.548 3.57812C122.783 4.14062 122.9 4.77734 122.9 5.48828C122.9 6.19141 122.771 6.83594 122.513 7.42188C122.255 8.00781 121.923 8.52344 121.517 8.96875C120.705 9.85938 119.759 10.4336 118.681 10.6914C119.463 11.0898 120.306 12.0547 121.213 13.5859L122.56 15.8828C123.255 17.0312 123.798 17.6055 124.189 17.6055C124.494 17.6211 124.826 17.5703 125.185 17.4531L125.127 19H123.345C122.166 19 121.213 18.5977 120.486 17.793C120.127 17.3398 119.81 16.7539 119.537 16.0352L118.892 14.3945C118.603 13.6758 118.259 13.0547 117.861 12.5312C117.463 12 117.127 11.6445 116.853 11.4648C116.353 11.1445 115.572 10.9844 114.509 10.9844H113.525V15.7188C113.525 16.4609 113.584 16.9375 113.701 17.1484ZM117.908 2.5C117.408 2.33594 116.963 2.25391 116.572 2.25391H115.119C114.533 2.25391 114.002 2.31641 113.525 2.44141V9.57812H116.349C117.412 9.5625 118.298 9.23438 119.009 8.59375C119.767 7.89844 120.146 6.98438 120.146 5.85156C120.146 4.08594 119.4 2.96875 117.908 2.5ZM134.288 17.2305C134.405 17.418 134.55 17.5469 134.722 17.6172C134.902 17.6797 135.097 17.7109 135.308 17.7109C135.527 17.7109 135.929 17.6523 136.515 17.5352L136.374 19H129.191L129.32 17.7109C130.085 17.7109 130.64 17.5312 130.984 17.1719C131.382 16.7422 131.581 16.0195 131.581 15.0039L131.57 4.77344C131.57 3.44531 131.37 2.69141 130.972 2.51172C130.847 2.45703 130.702 2.42969 130.538 2.42969C130.077 2.42969 129.659 2.46484 129.284 2.53516L129.472 1.07031H136.327L136.14 2.42969C135.257 2.42969 134.695 2.57813 134.452 2.875C134.226 3.14063 134.113 3.74609 134.113 4.69141V15.8242C134.113 16.5742 134.171 17.043 134.288 17.2305ZM148.548 19.1758L144.634 19.0117L141.341 19L141.423 17.7109C142.126 17.7109 142.595 17.6094 142.829 17.4062C143.243 17.0469 143.45 16.4609 143.45 15.6484V4.59766C143.45 3.77734 143.368 3.24609 143.204 3.00391C143.04 2.75391 142.88 2.59375 142.723 2.52344C142.567 2.45312 142.372 2.41797 142.137 2.41797C141.903 2.41797 141.634 2.46484 141.329 2.55859L141.446 1.07031H144.399L148.677 0.894531C154.739 0.894531 157.77 3.76953 157.77 9.51953C157.77 12.4336 156.93 14.7695 155.251 16.5273C153.563 18.293 151.329 19.1758 148.548 19.1758ZM149.919 2.40625C149.302 2.30469 148.665 2.25391 148.009 2.25391C147.36 2.25391 146.688 2.33203 145.993 2.48828V16.5625C145.993 16.9531 146.02 17.1953 146.075 17.2891C146.137 17.3828 146.227 17.4531 146.345 17.5C146.462 17.5391 146.63 17.5703 146.848 17.5938C147.223 17.6328 147.887 17.6523 148.841 17.6523C149.802 17.6523 150.649 17.5117 151.384 17.2305C152.118 16.9414 152.751 16.4922 153.282 15.8828C154.407 14.5781 154.97 12.6367 154.97 10.0586C154.97 5.51172 153.286 2.96094 149.919 2.40625ZM178.299 17.8633C176.752 18.7461 174.553 19.1875 171.702 19.1875C168.491 19.1875 166.057 18.375 164.401 16.75C162.815 15.1953 162.022 13.0273 162.022 10.2461C162.022 7.70703 162.811 5.5625 164.389 3.8125C165.498 2.59375 166.959 1.74219 168.772 1.25781C169.702 1.01562 170.627 0.894531 171.549 0.894531C172.627 0.894531 173.655 0.953125 174.631 1.07031C176.163 1.26563 177.166 1.36328 177.643 1.36328L178.065 1.35156C178.065 2.84375 177.955 4.41797 177.737 6.07422H176.108C176.014 4.55859 175.67 3.52344 175.077 2.96875C174.491 2.41406 173.51 2.13672 172.135 2.13672C170.76 2.13672 169.616 2.34766 168.702 2.76953C167.795 3.18359 167.057 3.74219 166.487 4.44531C165.401 5.78125 164.858 7.57812 164.858 9.83594C164.858 13.5547 166.178 15.9922 168.819 17.1484C169.772 17.5625 170.83 17.7695 171.995 17.7695C173.87 17.7695 175.073 17.4258 175.604 16.7383V13.1289C175.604 12.0039 175.17 11.3984 174.303 11.3125C174.069 11.2891 173.78 11.2773 173.436 11.2773C173.092 11.2773 172.768 11.3047 172.463 11.3594L172.58 9.77734H179.705L179.541 11.2539C179.174 11.2617 178.885 11.3008 178.674 11.3711C178.463 11.4336 178.303 11.5781 178.194 11.8047C178.03 12.1562 177.948 13.0547 177.948 14.5C177.948 16.1719 178.065 17.293 178.299 17.8633ZM194.34 11.9688L194.316 12.3438H192.875C192.82 11.4609 192.719 10.9062 192.57 10.6797C192.305 10.2812 191.824 10.082 191.129 10.082H188.773V15.7305C188.773 16.4883 188.918 16.9922 189.207 17.2422C189.488 17.4844 190.094 17.6211 191.023 17.6523H193.262C194.824 17.6523 195.902 16.9766 196.496 15.625C196.684 15.2031 196.809 14.7266 196.871 14.1953H198.324C198.324 15.0859 198.234 16.0234 198.055 17.0078L197.703 19H184.168L184.367 17.7109C185.148 17.7109 185.66 17.5391 185.902 17.1953C186.121 16.8984 186.23 16.3008 186.23 15.4023V4.69141C186.23 3.18359 185.891 2.42969 185.211 2.42969C184.93 2.42969 184.633 2.46484 184.32 2.53516L184.461 1.07031H193.555C195.438 1.07031 196.848 1.00781 197.785 0.882812C197.785 2.13281 197.664 3.38281 197.422 4.63281C197.359 4.92969 197.305 5.15625 197.258 5.3125H196.062C195.984 4.04688 195.742 3.24609 195.336 2.91016C195.109 2.72266 194.812 2.60547 194.445 2.55859C194.086 2.51172 193.633 2.48828 193.086 2.48828H188.773V8.75781H191.199C191.98 8.75781 192.492 8.58984 192.734 8.25391C192.891 8.04297 193.016 7.55078 193.109 6.77734L194.539 6.76562L194.551 7.38672C194.551 8.37891 194.48 9.90625 194.34 11.9688Z" fill="black"/>
                </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for anything" class="search">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="teach-link">Teach On SkillBridge</a>
  <div class="cart-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 35 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_230_321)">
                    <path d="M26.0313 22.3999L30.3144 5.62954H35V2.99347H28.2669L27.2572 6.9468L0 6.9273L2.89785 22.3998H26.0313V22.3999ZM26.5842 9.5824L23.9839 19.7638H5.08602L3.176 9.56565L26.5842 9.5824Z" fill="black"/>
                    <path d="M22.4231 32.0066C24.7475 32.0066 26.6386 30.1154 26.6386 27.791C26.6386 25.4666 24.7475 23.5756 22.4231 23.5756H6.54073C4.2163 23.5756 2.3252 25.4666 2.3252 27.791C2.3252 30.1154 4.21626 32.0066 6.54073 32.0066C8.8652 32.0066 10.7562 30.1154 10.7562 27.791C10.7562 27.2328 10.6469 26.6997 10.4489 26.2116H18.5149C18.3169 26.6997 18.2075 27.2328 18.2075 27.791C18.2076 30.1154 20.0986 32.0066 22.4231 32.0066ZM8.12016 27.791C8.12016 28.662 7.41164 29.3705 6.54073 29.3705C5.66982 29.3705 4.96126 28.662 4.96126 27.791C4.96126 26.9201 5.66978 26.2116 6.54073 26.2116C7.41164 26.2116 8.12016 26.9201 8.12016 27.791ZM24.0025 27.791C24.0025 28.662 23.294 29.3705 22.4231 29.3705C21.5522 29.3705 20.8437 28.662 20.8437 27.791C20.8437 26.9201 21.5522 26.2116 22.4231 26.2116C23.294 26.2116 24.0025 26.9201 24.0025 27.791Z" fill="black"/>
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                    <clipPath id="clip0_230_321">
                    <rect width="35" height="35" fill="white"/>
                    </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                    </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="login-btn">Log in</a>
  <a href="#" class="signup-btn">Sign up</a>
</header>




Flexboxes have a number of options for managing spacing between items and the arrangement of boxes along a line. In this snippet I have styled the flex header with justify-content: space-evenly, but read about the other options too.


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 85px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: aliceblue;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.logo svg {
  width: 80px;
}

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-bar .search {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #B8B8B8;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  color: #B8B8B8;
}

.search[type=text] {
  background-color: #F9FAFB;
  background-image: url('Icon_awesome-search.svg');
  background-position: 25px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.teach-link, .login-btn, .signup-btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.teach-link {
  font-size: 13px;
  align-items: center;
}

.login-btn, .signup-btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.signup-btn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
<header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <svg width="199" height="20" viewBox="0 0 199 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M12.7344 1.11719C12.75 1.42969 12.7578 1.98047 12.7578 2.76953C12.7578 3.55078 12.6328 4.61328 12.3828 5.95703H11.0938C11.0469 3.98047 10.2656 2.78906 8.75 2.38281C8.27344 2.25 7.71094 2.18359 7.0625 2.18359C6.41406 2.18359 5.86328 2.26953 5.41016 2.44141C4.96484 2.61328 4.61719 2.83594 4.36719 3.10938C3.92188 3.58594 3.71875 4.21094 3.75781 4.98438C3.82031 6.17188 4.67969 7.19531 6.33594 8.05469C6.82812 8.3125 7.32031 8.55078 7.8125 8.76953C8.3125 8.98828 8.77734 9.20703 9.20703 9.42578C9.64453 9.63672 10.0664 9.87109 10.4727 10.1289C10.8789 10.3789 11.2578 10.6484 11.6094 10.9375C11.9688 11.2266 12.2852 11.543 12.5586 11.8867C13.1367 12.6211 13.457 13.4141 13.5195 14.2656C13.5195 15.8516 12.8906 17.0859 11.6328 17.9688C10.4688 18.7812 8.93359 19.1875 7.02734 19.1875C6.41797 19.1875 5.56641 19.0859 4.47266 18.8828C3.37891 18.6797 2.61719 18.5781 2.1875 18.5781C1.76562 18.5781 1.39844 18.6016 1.08594 18.6484L0.992188 18.625C0.984375 18.4531 0.980469 18.2812 0.980469 18.1094V17.6172C0.980469 15.9688 1.07031 14.6328 1.25 13.6094H2.57422C2.66797 15.8047 3.46094 17.1484 4.95312 17.6406C5.48438 17.8203 6.08203 17.9102 6.74609 17.9102C7.41797 17.9102 7.99609 17.8359 8.48047 17.6875C8.96484 17.5312 9.37891 17.3203 9.72266 17.0547C10.4414 16.5 10.8008 15.7891 10.8008 14.9219C10.7227 13.6875 9.78125 12.6406 7.97656 11.7812C7.45312 11.5312 7.03125 11.3359 6.71094 11.1953L6.11328 10.9375C6.02734 10.8984 5.81641 10.8086 5.48047 10.668C5.15234 10.5273 4.71094 10.2852 4.15625 9.94141C3.60938 9.59766 3.12109 9.20312 2.69141 8.75781C1.75391 7.78125 1.26953 6.66797 1.23828 5.41797C1.20703 4.06641 1.76562 2.96875 2.91406 2.125C4.03906 1.30469 5.51562 0.894531 7.34375 0.894531C7.625 0.894531 8.05469 0.929688 8.63281 1L10.1094 1.1875C10.5312 1.24219 10.9531 1.26953 11.375 1.26953C11.8047 1.26953 12.2578 1.21875 12.7344 1.11719ZM34.2008 2.45312C34.0914 2.42187 34.0133 2.40625 33.9664 2.40625C33.9273 2.40625 33.8141 2.41016 33.6266 2.41797C33.4391 2.42578 33.2555 2.46094 33.0758 2.52344C32.9039 2.57813 32.6969 2.6875 32.4547 2.85156C31.9 3.25 31.2633 3.86328 30.5445 4.69141L26.3258 9.55469C27.4742 10.3672 28.8219 11.7188 30.3687 13.6094C30.7828 14.125 31.1344 14.5938 31.4234 15.0156C31.7203 15.4297 31.9977 15.8047 32.2555 16.1406C32.5133 16.4688 32.7594 16.75 32.9937 16.9844C33.4625 17.4531 33.8609 17.6875 34.1891 17.6875C34.525 17.6875 34.8219 17.6523 35.0797 17.582L35.0328 19H32.2789C31.4195 19 30.6344 18.5508 29.9234 17.6523C29.6812 17.3477 29.4547 17.0156 29.2437 16.6562C28.6109 15.625 28.1461 14.8906 27.8492 14.4531L26.9703 13.1875C25.9703 11.8125 25.1422 10.8711 24.4859 10.3633H23.3961V15.4844C23.3961 16.2656 23.4469 16.7812 23.5484 17.0312C23.7437 17.4844 24.0875 17.7109 24.5797 17.7109C24.9 17.7109 25.2984 17.6562 25.775 17.5469L25.6227 19H18.9195L19.0602 17.7109C19.818 17.7109 20.3062 17.5547 20.525 17.2422C20.7437 16.9297 20.8531 16.2227 20.8531 15.1211V4.67969C20.8531 3.83594 20.8023 3.29297 20.7008 3.05078C20.607 2.80078 20.4977 2.63672 20.3727 2.55859C20.2477 2.47266 20.1187 2.42969 19.9859 2.42969C19.8609 2.42969 19.7516 2.43359 19.6578 2.44141C19.5641 2.44141 19.4625 2.44531 19.3531 2.45312L19.0484 2.47656C18.9469 2.48438 18.857 2.49219 18.7789 2.5L18.9898 1.07031H25.3297L25.1539 2.42969C24.482 2.42969 24.0484 2.53125 23.8531 2.73438C23.5484 3.07031 23.3961 3.67969 23.3961 4.5625V9.01562H24.2047C24.4703 9.01562 24.6852 8.94922 24.8492 8.81641L28.1656 5.00781C28.4859 4.63281 28.6812 4.38672 28.7516 4.26953C28.9 4.02734 29.0289 3.83594 29.1383 3.69531C29.443 3.33594 29.5953 3.08203 29.5953 2.93359C29.5953 2.54297 29.3844 2.34766 28.9625 2.34766C28.5797 2.34766 28.2242 2.38281 27.8961 2.45312L28.0953 1.07031H34.4117L34.2008 2.45312ZM44.218 17.2305C44.3352 17.418 44.4797 17.5469 44.6516 17.6172C44.8312 17.6797 45.0266 17.7109 45.2375 17.7109C45.4562 17.7109 45.8586 17.6523 46.4445 17.5352L46.3039 19H39.1203L39.2492 17.7109C40.0148 17.7109 40.5695 17.5312 40.9133 17.1719C41.3117 16.7422 41.5109 16.0195 41.5109 15.0039L41.4992 4.77344C41.4992 3.44531 41.3 2.69141 40.9016 2.51172C40.7766 2.45703 40.632 2.42969 40.468 2.42969C40.007 2.42969 39.5891 2.46484 39.2141 2.53516L39.4016 1.07031H46.257L46.0695 2.42969C45.1867 2.42969 44.6242 2.57813 44.382 2.875C44.1555 3.14063 44.0422 3.74609 44.0422 4.69141V15.8242C44.0422 16.5742 44.1008 17.043 44.218 17.2305ZM65.1102 13.7617C65.1492 14.1914 65.1688 14.6367 65.1688 15.0977C65.1688 15.7461 65.0984 16.4531 64.9578 17.2188C64.7703 18.2031 64.6688 18.7969 64.6531 19H50.9188L51.0594 17.6523C51.8094 17.668 52.3328 17.5156 52.6297 17.1953C52.9813 16.8281 53.157 16.1367 53.157 15.1211L53.1453 4.375C53.1453 3.53125 53.0906 3.01562 52.9813 2.82812C52.8719 2.64062 52.7547 2.52734 52.6297 2.48828C52.5125 2.44922 52.3445 2.42969 52.1258 2.42969C51.9148 2.42969 51.7313 2.44531 51.575 2.47656C51.3875 2.52344 51.2625 2.54688 51.2 2.54688L51.3875 1.07031H58.4188L58.2547 2.44141C57.2469 2.44141 56.618 2.51953 56.368 2.67578C56.118 2.83203 55.9461 3.03516 55.8523 3.28516C55.7664 3.53516 55.7234 3.875 55.7234 4.30469L55.7352 4.66797V15.7188C55.7352 16.875 56.118 17.5195 56.8836 17.6523C57.1102 17.6914 57.3523 17.7109 57.6102 17.7109H59.5438C61.6922 17.7109 62.9734 16.8867 63.3875 15.2383C63.5125 14.7617 63.6023 14.2695 63.657 13.7617H65.1102ZM83.5414 13.7617C83.5805 14.1914 83.6 14.6367 83.6 15.0977C83.6 15.7461 83.5297 16.4531 83.3891 17.2188C83.2016 18.2031 83.1 18.7969 83.0844 19H69.35L69.4906 17.6523C70.2406 17.668 70.7641 17.5156 71.0609 17.1953C71.4125 16.8281 71.5883 16.1367 71.5883 15.1211L71.5766 4.375C71.5766 3.53125 71.5219 3.01562 71.4125 2.82812C71.3031 2.64062 71.1859 2.52734 71.0609 2.48828C70.9437 2.44922 70.7758 2.42969 70.557 2.42969C70.3461 2.42969 70.1625 2.44531 70.0062 2.47656C69.8187 2.52344 69.6937 2.54688 69.6312 2.54688L69.8187 1.07031H76.85L76.6859 2.44141C75.6781 2.44141 75.0492 2.51953 74.7992 2.67578C74.5492 2.83203 74.3773 3.03516 74.2836 3.28516C74.1977 3.53516 74.1547 3.875 74.1547 4.30469L74.1664 4.66797V15.7188C74.1664 16.875 74.5492 17.5195 75.3148 17.6523C75.5414 17.6914 75.7836 17.7109 76.0414 17.7109H77.975C80.1234 17.7109 81.4047 16.8867 81.8187 15.2383C81.9437 14.7617 82.0336 14.2695 82.0883 13.7617H83.5414ZM96.2539 19.1875L91.8477 19.0117H88.2617L88.3555 17.7109C89.0664 17.7109 89.5508 17.6172 89.8086 17.4297C90.2695 17.0781 90.5 16.5 90.5 15.6953V4.67969C90.5 3.4375 90.2578 2.71875 89.7734 2.52344C89.6328 2.46094 89.4023 2.42969 89.082 2.42969C88.7617 2.42969 88.4961 2.47266 88.2852 2.55859L88.3906 1.07031H91.8477C92.3789 1.05469 92.8945 1.03516 93.3945 1.01172C94.7383 0.933594 95.8242 0.894531 96.6523 0.894531C97.4883 0.894531 98.2852 0.996094 99.043 1.19922C99.8086 1.39453 100.445 1.67578 100.953 2.04297C101.977 2.78516 102.488 3.8125 102.488 5.125C102.488 6.16406 102.18 7.07031 101.562 7.84375C101.055 8.47656 100.371 8.96484 99.5117 9.30859C100.973 9.44141 102.094 9.92969 102.875 10.7734C103.578 11.5234 103.93 12.457 103.93 13.5742C103.93 15.207 103.273 16.5352 101.961 17.5586C100.562 18.6445 98.6602 19.1875 96.2539 19.1875ZM99.6875 5.35938C99.6875 3.28906 98.3281 2.25391 95.6094 2.25391C94.7109 2.25391 94.0977 2.28906 93.7695 2.35938L93.043 2.5V8.98047H96.4531C98.1406 8.98047 99.1602 8.30078 99.5117 6.94141C99.6289 6.48828 99.6875 5.96094 99.6875 5.35938ZM93.043 10.3398L93.0664 16.2344C93.0664 16.8906 93.3047 17.3242 93.7812 17.5352C94.2344 17.7305 95.0391 17.8281 96.1953 17.8281C97.3516 17.8281 98.2188 17.7305 98.7969 17.5352C99.3828 17.332 99.8438 17.0508 100.18 16.6914C100.781 16.0586 101.082 15.0859 101.082 13.7734C101.082 12.4609 100.734 11.5625 100.039 11.0781C99.3203 10.5781 97.9727 10.3281 95.9961 10.3281L93.043 10.3398ZM113.701 17.1484C113.826 17.3594 113.974 17.5078 114.146 17.5938C114.318 17.6719 114.568 17.7109 114.896 17.7109C115.232 17.7109 115.65 17.6484 116.15 17.5234L116.021 19H109.107L109.248 17.7109C110.052 17.6953 110.564 17.4844 110.783 17.0781C110.97 16.75 111.064 16.0234 111.064 14.8984L111.052 4.33984C111.052 3.57422 111.017 3.10156 110.947 2.92188C110.806 2.59375 110.486 2.42969 109.986 2.42969C109.588 2.42969 109.181 2.47656 108.767 2.57031L108.955 1.07031H112.33L117.088 0.894531C119.963 0.894531 121.783 1.78906 122.548 3.57812C122.783 4.14062 122.9 4.77734 122.9 5.48828C122.9 6.19141 122.771 6.83594 122.513 7.42188C122.255 8.00781 121.923 8.52344 121.517 8.96875C120.705 9.85938 119.759 10.4336 118.681 10.6914C119.463 11.0898 120.306 12.0547 121.213 13.5859L122.56 15.8828C123.255 17.0312 123.798 17.6055 124.189 17.6055C124.494 17.6211 124.826 17.5703 125.185 17.4531L125.127 19H123.345C122.166 19 121.213 18.5977 120.486 17.793C120.127 17.3398 119.81 16.7539 119.537 16.0352L118.892 14.3945C118.603 13.6758 118.259 13.0547 117.861 12.5312C117.463 12 117.127 11.6445 116.853 11.4648C116.353 11.1445 115.572 10.9844 114.509 10.9844H113.525V15.7188C113.525 16.4609 113.584 16.9375 113.701 17.1484ZM117.908 2.5C117.408 2.33594 116.963 2.25391 116.572 2.25391H115.119C114.533 2.25391 114.002 2.31641 113.525 2.44141V9.57812H116.349C117.412 9.5625 118.298 9.23438 119.009 8.59375C119.767 7.89844 120.146 6.98438 120.146 5.85156C120.146 4.08594 119.4 2.96875 117.908 2.5ZM134.288 17.2305C134.405 17.418 134.55 17.5469 134.722 17.6172C134.902 17.6797 135.097 17.7109 135.308 17.7109C135.527 17.7109 135.929 17.6523 136.515 17.5352L136.374 19H129.191L129.32 17.7109C130.085 17.7109 130.64 17.5312 130.984 17.1719C131.382 16.7422 131.581 16.0195 131.581 15.0039L131.57 4.77344C131.57 3.44531 131.37 2.69141 130.972 2.51172C130.847 2.45703 130.702 2.42969 130.538 2.42969C130.077 2.42969 129.659 2.46484 129.284 2.53516L129.472 1.07031H136.327L136.14 2.42969C135.257 2.42969 134.695 2.57813 134.452 2.875C134.226 3.14063 134.113 3.74609 134.113 4.69141V15.8242C134.113 16.5742 134.171 17.043 134.288 17.2305ZM148.548 19.1758L144.634 19.0117L141.341 19L141.423 17.7109C142.126 17.7109 142.595 17.6094 142.829 17.4062C143.243 17.0469 143.45 16.4609 143.45 15.6484V4.59766C143.45 3.77734 143.368 3.24609 143.204 3.00391C143.04 2.75391 142.88 2.59375 142.723 2.52344C142.567 2.45312 142.372 2.41797 142.137 2.41797C141.903 2.41797 141.634 2.46484 141.329 2.55859L141.446 1.07031H144.399L148.677 0.894531C154.739 0.894531 157.77 3.76953 157.77 9.51953C157.77 12.4336 156.93 14.7695 155.251 16.5273C153.563 18.293 151.329 19.1758 148.548 19.1758ZM149.919 2.40625C149.302 2.30469 148.665 2.25391 148.009 2.25391C147.36 2.25391 146.688 2.33203 145.993 2.48828V16.5625C145.993 16.9531 146.02 17.1953 146.075 17.2891C146.137 17.3828 146.227 17.4531 146.345 17.5C146.462 17.5391 146.63 17.5703 146.848 17.5938C147.223 17.6328 147.887 17.6523 148.841 17.6523C149.802 17.6523 150.649 17.5117 151.384 17.2305C152.118 16.9414 152.751 16.4922 153.282 15.8828C154.407 14.5781 154.97 12.6367 154.97 10.0586C154.97 5.51172 153.286 2.96094 149.919 2.40625ZM178.299 17.8633C176.752 18.7461 174.553 19.1875 171.702 19.1875C168.491 19.1875 166.057 18.375 164.401 16.75C162.815 15.1953 162.022 13.0273 162.022 10.2461C162.022 7.70703 162.811 5.5625 164.389 3.8125C165.498 2.59375 166.959 1.74219 168.772 1.25781C169.702 1.01562 170.627 0.894531 171.549 0.894531C172.627 0.894531 173.655 0.953125 174.631 1.07031C176.163 1.26563 177.166 1.36328 177.643 1.36328L178.065 1.35156C178.065 2.84375 177.955 4.41797 177.737 6.07422H176.108C176.014 4.55859 175.67 3.52344 175.077 2.96875C174.491 2.41406 173.51 2.13672 172.135 2.13672C170.76 2.13672 169.616 2.34766 168.702 2.76953C167.795 3.18359 167.057 3.74219 166.487 4.44531C165.401 5.78125 164.858 7.57812 164.858 9.83594C164.858 13.5547 166.178 15.9922 168.819 17.1484C169.772 17.5625 170.83 17.7695 171.995 17.7695C173.87 17.7695 175.073 17.4258 175.604 16.7383V13.1289C175.604 12.0039 175.17 11.3984 174.303 11.3125C174.069 11.2891 173.78 11.2773 173.436 11.2773C173.092 11.2773 172.768 11.3047 172.463 11.3594L172.58 9.77734H179.705L179.541 11.2539C179.174 11.2617 178.885 11.3008 178.674 11.3711C178.463 11.4336 178.303 11.5781 178.194 11.8047C178.03 12.1562 177.948 13.0547 177.948 14.5C177.948 16.1719 178.065 17.293 178.299 17.8633ZM194.34 11.9688L194.316 12.3438H192.875C192.82 11.4609 192.719 10.9062 192.57 10.6797C192.305 10.2812 191.824 10.082 191.129 10.082H188.773V15.7305C188.773 16.4883 188.918 16.9922 189.207 17.2422C189.488 17.4844 190.094 17.6211 191.023 17.6523H193.262C194.824 17.6523 195.902 16.9766 196.496 15.625C196.684 15.2031 196.809 14.7266 196.871 14.1953H198.324C198.324 15.0859 198.234 16.0234 198.055 17.0078L197.703 19H184.168L184.367 17.7109C185.148 17.7109 185.66 17.5391 185.902 17.1953C186.121 16.8984 186.23 16.3008 186.23 15.4023V4.69141C186.23 3.18359 185.891 2.42969 185.211 2.42969C184.93 2.42969 184.633 2.46484 184.32 2.53516L184.461 1.07031H193.555C195.438 1.07031 196.848 1.00781 197.785 0.882812C197.785 2.13281 197.664 3.38281 197.422 4.63281C197.359 4.92969 197.305 5.15625 197.258 5.3125H196.062C195.984 4.04688 195.742 3.24609 195.336 2.91016C195.109 2.72266 194.812 2.60547 194.445 2.55859C194.086 2.51172 193.633 2.48828 193.086 2.48828H188.773V8.75781H191.199C191.98 8.75781 192.492 8.58984 192.734 8.25391C192.891 8.04297 193.016 7.55078 193.109 6.77734L194.539 6.76562L194.551 7.38672C194.551 8.37891 194.48 9.90625 194.34 11.9688Z" fill="black"/>
                </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search for anything" class="search">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="teach-link">Teach On SB</a>
        <div class="cart-icon">
            <a href="#">
                <svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 35 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_230_321)">
                    <path d="M26.0313 22.3999L30.3144 5.62954H35V2.99347H28.2669L27.2572 6.9468L0 6.9273L2.89785 22.3998H26.0313V22.3999ZM26.5842 9.5824L23.9839 19.7638H5.08602L3.176 9.56565L26.5842 9.5824Z" fill="black"/>
                    <path d="M22.4231 32.0066C24.7475 32.0066 26.6386 30.1154 26.6386 27.791C26.6386 25.4666 24.7475 23.5756 22.4231 23.5756H6.54073C4.2163 23.5756 2.3252 25.4666 2.3252 27.791C2.3252 30.1154 4.21626 32.0066 6.54073 32.0066C8.8652 32.0066 10.7562 30.1154 10.7562 27.791C10.7562 27.2328 10.6469 26.6997 10.4489 26.2116H18.5149C18.3169 26.6997 18.2075 27.2328 18.2075 27.791C18.2076 30.1154 20.0986 32.0066 22.4231 32.0066ZM8.12016 27.791C8.12016 28.662 7.41164 29.3705 6.54073 29.3705C5.66982 29.3705 4.96126 28.662 4.96126 27.791C4.96126 26.9201 5.66978 26.2116 6.54073 26.2116C7.41164 26.2116 8.12016 26.9201 8.12016 27.791ZM24.0025 27.791C24.0025 28.662 23.294 29.3705 22.4231 29.3705C21.5522 29.3705 20.8437 28.662 20.8437 27.791C20.8437 26.9201 21.5522 26.2116 22.4231 26.2116C23.294 26.2116 24.0025 26.9201 24.0025 27.791Z" fill="black"/>
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                    <clipPath id="clip0_230_321">
                    <rect width="35" height="35" fill="white"/>
                    </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                    </svg>   
            </a>             
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="login-btn">Log in</a>
          <a href="#" class="signup-btn">Sign up</a>
        </div>
</header>



